# How to transfer session from Firefox to python requests?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have code on my server

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding= utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display 
import requests
import browsercookie

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.youporn.com/login/") 
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("login_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("login_password")
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btnLogin")
username.send_keys("phillipssadella")
password.send_keys("GmiN97RUC")
button.click()
time.sleep(10)
txt = open("driver.html", "w")
txt.write(browser.page_source)
cookies = browser.get_cookies()
print cookies
s = requests.Session()
cook = [s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value']) for c in cookies]
print cook
r = requests.get("https://www.youporn.com/", cookies=cook)
txt = open("requests.html", "w")
txt.write(r.content)
browser.close()
display.stop()
```

I log in using selenium and in debug (driver.html) - I see that I'm inside account. It's ok.

Now I want to transfer this session to requests. I want that requests use already authorized session.

I extract cookies from Firefox and try to push it to requests. But I see error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://www.youporn.com/", cookies=cook)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 415, in prepare_request
    cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(cookies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 518, in cookiejar_from_dict
    cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name]))
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I tried

```
for cookie in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
    print cookie
r = s.get("https://www.youporn.com/", cookies=cookies)
```

result

```
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'sid', u'value': u'6759444914875662336', u'expiry': 1924956113, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'_gat', u'value': u'1', u'expiry': 1509245409, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'www.youporn.com', u'name': u'performance_timing', u'value': u'Other', u'expiry': None, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'login', u'value': u'phillipssadella%7C60a49468b4179a3a048d0dd7b0b14441c87f4a3b%7C4c7fc449ca6db2a1b20ea1611669aa29', u'expiry': 1511837364, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': True, u'secure': True}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'username', u'value': u'phillipssadella', u'expiry': 1511837364, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': True}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'_ga', u'value': u'GA1.2.1764019650.1509245349', u'expiry': 1572317365, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'_gid', u'value': u'GA1.2.1990953556.1509245349', u'expiry': 1509331765, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'yp-device', u'value': u'pc', u'expiry': 1509331769, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.youporn.com', u'name': u'country', u'value': u'IT', u'expiry': 1924956114, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
```

The traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    r = s.get("https://www.youporn.com/", cookies=cookies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 415, in prepare_request
    cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(cookies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 518, in cookiejar_from_dict
    cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

How can I make this correctly?

Comment: please post the entire traceback for the error

Comment: Are you sure you want to use requests?  It will not behave as a browser.  It does not do javascript.

Comment: @0TTT0  traceback added

Comment: @John Gordon  I know. I have all code on requests. Only auth I need with js support. That's why selenium + requests

Comment: The problem may be that `cook` is a _list_ of `Cookie` objects, instead of a dict (or a `CookieJar` object) as the `cookies=` parameter expects.  Also, since you've already gone to the trouble of setting all the cookies in `s.cookies`, why not use `s.get()`?

Comment: @John Gordon TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error traceback, so I have an idea where it is happening.

Comment: @John Gordon  I added the result dictionary and full traceback

Comment: You're already setting each cookie in `s.cookies`, so you shouldn't need to also pass the cookies as an argument.  Try just leaving off the `cookies=` parameter to `s.get()`.

Comment: @John Gordon  The error disappear, but requests get page as not log in. I mean requests.html - no login inside account

Comment: I'm afraid I've run out of ideas.  Maybe someone else will have a solution.